# How group action of $G$ on set $\Omega$ acts on the vector space induced by $\Omega$, $\mathcal{X}(\Omega)$?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, group-actions

A left group action of $G$ on a set $\Omega$ is mapping $G \times \Omega \to \Omega$. We define a space of $\mathcal{C}$ valued signals as $\mathcal{X}(\Omega.\mathcal{C}) = \{x:\Omega \to \mathcal{C}\}$ has a vector space property. As a typical illustration, take $\Omega = \mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_n$ as a two dimensional $n \times n$ grids, $x$ is RGB image(i.e. a signal $x: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$). Now if we want to obtain the group action of $G$ on the space $\mathcal{X}(\Omega)$ we have:
\begin{align}
   (g \cdot x)(u) = x(g^{-1}u) \tag{1}
\end{align}
where $g \in G, x \in \mathcal{X}, u \in \Omega$. I got the equation $1$ from [the paper, Geometric Deep Learning Grids, Groups, Graphs, Geodesics, and Gauges](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.13478.pdf) (page 14 equation 3). The authors of this paper did not give any intuitive understanding of the equation $1$ also did not mention where to find the proof. Can anyone please help me to understand how this formula actually work?

Comment: Is $\mathcal{C}$ supposed to be $\mathbb{C}$, the complex numbers?

Comment: The action of $G$ on $\Omega$ is a permutation; the elements of $\Omega$ index a basis for $\mathcal{X}$; $x(u)$ is the $u$th coordinate of $x$. The action shuffles the basis according to the action of $G$.

Comment: The definition of the action on $\mathcal X(\Omega)$ might be easier to understand in the following equivalent form: If $x$ puts color $c$ at position $p$, then $gx$ puts the same color $c$ at position $gp$. So the colors given by $x$ don't change but get moved to new posiitons according to the action of $g$ on $\Omega$.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin,  $\mathcal{C}$ does not only imply complex numbers. For above example of RGB images $\mathcal{C}=\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Additional information on a related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4510703/group-action-for-signal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They've defined a new group action $G \times \mathcal{X}(\Omega) \to \mathcal{X}(\Omega)$ using the old group action $G \times \Omega \to \Omega$.

If you have $x \in \mathcal{X}(\Omega)$, they define $g \cdot x$ as a signal $u \mapsto x(g^{-1} u)$ which belongs to $\mathcal{X}(\Omega)$. (I guess one should check that this satisfies the conditions that a group action must satisfy, like $(gh) \cdot x = g \cdot (h \cdot x)$.)

Comment: thanks for the explanation, yes equation 1 satisfy the condition for group action. I have one question, is there any explanation why one would define group operation like eqn 1?

Comment: @SwaksharDeb See the comments by Arturo Magidin and Andreas Blass. I think the intuition of "applying color $x(u)$ to point $gu$ instead of to $u$" (i.e. $(g \cdot x)(gu) := x(u)$) is a good way to understand the motivation of the definition.